# Simple linear regression model

Tags: python, linear-regression

Please help me. After splitting my data into

`X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = train_test_split(X,y)`

then passing it to my linear regression model I.e

`linereg = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)`

It brings out an error saying array must be 2D not 1D array. How can I make it a 2D array.

Comment: The error is happening because `X` needs to be a 2D array-like. Do you understand what that means?

Comment: This is tagged with Swift & Python, why?

Comment: You can just reshape X_train to be a 2D array-like.

Comment: No,  please help me out

Comment: could you give us: `X_train.shape` and the orginal dataframe...

Answer (score 1):

first split the data correctly

```
X_train, x_test, Y_train,y_test=train_test_split(features,labels,train_size=0.7, test_size=0.3, random_state=2)
```

try reshaping the x_train and x_test using reshape method.

```
x_test=x_test.reshape(-1,1)
x_train=x_train.reshape(-1,1)
```